# JSON.NET: Minify/Format content without re-parsing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is it possible to minify/format a JSON string using the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library without forcing the system to reparse the code?  This is what I have for my methods:

```
public async Task<string> Minify(string json)
{
    // TODO: Some way to do this without a re-parse?
    var jsonObj = await JsonOpener.GetJsonFromString(json);
    return jsonObj.ToString(Formatting.None);
}

public async Task<string> Beautify(string json)
{
    // TODO: Some way to do this without a re-parse?
    var jsonObj = await JsonOpener.GetJsonFromString(json);
    return FormatJson(jsonObj);
}

private string FormatJson(JToken input)
{
    // We could just do input.ToString(Formatting.Indented), but this allows us
    // to take advantage of JsonTextWriter's formatting options.
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()))
    {
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            // Configures indentation character and indentation width
            // (e.g., "indent each level using 2 spaces", or "use tabs")
            ConfigureWriter(jsonWriter);
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, input);

            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works just fine in small blocks of JSON, but it starts to get bogged down with large blocks of content.  If I could just strip out everything without having to go through the parser, it would be much faster, I'd imagine.

If I have to reinvent the wheel and strip out all whitespace or whatnot myself, I will, but I don't know if there any gotchas that come into play.

For that matter, is there another library better suited to this?

**EDIT:** My bad, JSON does not support comments natively.

Comment: If you want the fastest way to do it then Json.NET is not the way to go but https://github.com/EgorBo/SimdJsonSharp. It is still beta but it contains a Minify option shown in the tests. This is a port of https://github.com/lemire/simdjson which was created by Daniel Lemire a Canadian professor. Even if you cannot switch over these libraries are a fascinating read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using Json.Net.  Just connect a `JsonTextReader` directly to a `JsonTextWriter`.  That way you are reusing the tokenizer logic of the reader and the formatting logic of the writer, but you skip the step of converting the tokens into an intermediate object representation and back (which is the time-consuming part).

Here is how I would break it into helper methods to make it super easy and flexible to use:

```
public static string Minify(string json)
{
    return ReformatJson(json, Formatting.None);
}

public static string Beautify(string json)
{
    return ReformatJson(json, Formatting.Indented);
}

public static string ReformatJson(string json, Formatting formatting)
{
    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(json))
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        ReformatJson(stringReader, stringWriter, formatting);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}

public static void ReformatJson(TextReader textReader, TextWriter textWriter, Formatting formatting)
{
    using (JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
    using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
    {
        jsonWriter.Formatting = formatting;
        jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
    }
}
```

Here is a short demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/RevZNU

With this setup you could easily add additional overloads that work on streams, too, if you needed it.  For example:

```
public static void Minify(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    ReformatJson(inputStream, outputStream, Formatting.None, encoding);
}

public static void Beautify(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    ReformatJson(inputStream, outputStream, Formatting.Indented, encoding);
}

public static void ReformatJson(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, Formatting formatting, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

    const int bufferSize = 1024;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream, encoding, true, bufferSize, true))
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream, encoding, bufferSize, true))
    {
        ReformatJson(streamReader, streamWriter, formatting);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. But why you're splitting `ReformatJson()` to two methods?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I split it into two so that it is easy to add support for streams if you need to.  In order to do that you would need to use a `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` instead of `StringReader` and `StringWriter`.  The last method is split out so that you can call it without duplicating code.  I've edited my post to show what I mean.

Comment: What would this look like with the new System.Text.Json API's?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73795129/edit). As I elaborate in my answer to the same question, Brian's code in this answer is the most performant I could find