# Remove white spaces from json after loading it from file using System.Text.Json in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I am using .NET Core 3.1 with `System.Text.Json` I am reading JSON from file

```
var jsonFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "WellKnownConfig.json");
if (System.IO.File.Exists(jsonFilename))
{
    var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilename);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileContent))
    {
         //var o = JsonDocument.Parse(fileContent);                        
         Result = new OkObjectResult(fileContent);
    }
    else
    {
        Result = new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

The problem is it is having whitespaces. anyway, I can remove white spaces without string parsing.
Like some way from `System.Text.Json` by loading into some object while using `JsonDocument` or `JsonSerializer`

Also is there some way I can minify this JSON after loading it from file

I have seen some solution for newtonjson

[Minify a json string using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633512/minify-a-json-string-using-net)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string)

Comment: What are you actually asking? JSON parsing ignores whitespace. *Values* with spaces in them aren't whitespace, they are values. The code you posted though doesn't parse anything. What do the input and expected output look like?

Comment: Wanted to avoid any string parsing. There might be some way while loading the json from some file to remove white space

Comment: @KamranShahid there's no whitespace in parsing. The question makes no sense - unless you ask how to convert indented JSON to unindented JSON?

Comment: People using System.Text.json (which is relevantly new) may know the answer

Comment: @KamranShahid and those people are saying the question makes no sense. Post input and expected output. Besides, reading text, deciding whether some input is whitespace or not and transforming it to something else *is* part of parsing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you ignore and let other see the problem. they might have an answer

Comment: @RahulSharma the question asks nothing about escaped text though. Why would Unescape help?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes, and the OP said nothing about escaped text.

Comment: @RahulSharma it won't. It will remove the white space *escape sequences*. If you use `Regex.Unescape("-  -")` you get `-  -`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos welldone for negative marking :)

Comment: @RahulSharma `Unescape` would work on `-\ \ -` and produce `-  -`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, you are right sir. Sorry I did not realize the actual usage of this method. Thank you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos let other atleast have some time to analyze the question. i respect your knowledge but for pity some negative point question never attract any audience which have face similar question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos check some similar sort of problem solved in newtonjson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633512/minify-a-json-string-using-net

Comment: This just removes indentation. It's neither minification nor whitespace removal. It parses the original JSON and serializes it again, without indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Did the trick. I hope it will help other's as well

```
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilename);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileContent) && Utility.IsValidJson(fileContent))
{
    var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(fileContent);
    Result = new OkObjectResult(obj);
}
else
{
    Result = new NoContentResult();
}
```

Comment: That's what you said you *didn't* want to do. It's also what your code already did halfway - parse the JSON string. If it *returned* the parsed object, you'd get an unindented string back

Comment: Since you want to unindent, the low-cost solution would be to read tokens one at a time with a Utf8JsonReader and write it out with a Utf8JsonWriter. This would avoid caching the entire object in memory, which is the typical reason people want to avoid parsing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos may be i have not explain it clearly but this was the thing i wnated to do. haven't used Utf8JsonReader but will google about it.
Thanks